# Best practice for performing inserts in a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to do some inserts in a cursor over about 300000 rows, this is however running slowly, any ideas on how i can make it run faster? Can i speed it up by batching the commits? So for example i would perform a commit after the 1000th row

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR test_cursor IS 
    SELECT a from database.mytable
BEGIN

  FOR curRow IN test_cursor LOOP

    insert into tableb (testval)
    values ('something');

  commit;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

300000 rows is not that many rows. Unless the rows are each **extremely** large, you should not commit in the middle of the batch.

Intermediate commits [will only achieve](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022):

- additional overhead because each commit creates additional work,
- loss of restartability in case of error (and loss of transactional integrity),
- greater chance of running into ORA-1555

If your process is really a cursor with a single insert inside the loop, you should run a single statement:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tableb (col1..coln) (SELECT col1..coln FROM database.mytable);
END;
```

If you still need extra performance, you could look into direct insert and parallel operation but It might be over-optimization with "only" 300k rows.

By far the single greatest optimization available to you is to think in term of *sets* instead of the traditional procedural approach that consists of batches of single row statements.

Comment: +1 For not committing inside a loop, in nearly all cases it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try this:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR test_cursor IS 
    SELECT col1 from table_a;

  TYPE fetch_array IS TABLE OF test_cursor%ROWTYPE;
  test_array fetch_array;

  l_errors                              PLS_INTEGER;
  l_dml_errors                          EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(l_dml_errors, -24381);    

BEGIN

  open test_cursor;
  loop
    fetch test_cursor bulk collect into test_array limit 10000;
    forall i in 1..test_array.count save exceptions
      insert into table_b(col1)
      values(test_array(i).col1);
      exit when test_cursor%notfound;
  end loop;
  close test_cursor;
  commit;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN l_dml_errors THEN
    l_errors := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of INSERT statements that failed: ' || l_errors);
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_errors
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('Error #' || i || ' at '|| 'iteration #' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX);
      dbms_output.put_line('Error message is ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Be careful with collections. Few weeks ago, I've been fighting memory leaks on our 10.2.0.3, which were caused by such bulk operations. We have found out, that this was a bug, that should be fixed in 10.2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend a cursor approach for this.  I use append parallel hints for situations like this.  Most of the time your query literally runs N times as fast where N is the parallel degree.  It is occasionally a good idea to bypass disaster recovery with nologging / noarchivelog.

For truly large migrations (dozens to hundreds of GB), I've found it's a good idea to batch on a table's natural key (date, usually).  Some small amount of state around it can let you cancel + resume the migration at will if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

May Be This will help you please try this

```
DECLARE
i number;
  CURSOR test_cursor IS 
    SELECT a from database.mytable
BEGIN

  FOR curRow IN test_cursor LOOP

    insert into tableb (testval)
    values ('something');
i:i+1;
if mod(i,1000)=0 then
  commit;
end if;
  END LOOP;
commit;
END;
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't attack the root cause, only reduces the number of commits instead of getting rid of the commits altogether, and above all: this code is not tested and does not work they way you intended.